# How to make app save data

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've made an app which basically you enter some text into. You can edit it but upon closing the application all data is lost.

Is there a tutorial to preserve data for the application?

How can i save the data is it by storing to a database or plist?

Comment: This post is a waste of storage, go to apples developer page to learn more about CoreData and SQL, search google man. Why ask such a basic question, SEARCH GOOGLE. Put some effort into learning it yourself, and come here for any errors you have in you code with the storing.

Answer (score 2):

There are hundreds of tutorials - but you also need to consider which method is best for your app. For saving small simple amounts of data (such as user settings) use `NSUserDefaults`. For more complicated data you could use `CoreData` or SQLite.

- NSUserDefaults - [NSUserDefaults - tutsplus.com](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)
- Core Data - [Core Data - raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)
- SQLite - [SQLite Tutorial - Add/Display/Delete - Xcode 4.5 - Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC3F8a4F_KE)

---

**NSUserDefaults** is as simple as:

1. To set an object:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:@"Patrick" forKey:@"username"];
   [defaults synchronize];
   ```
2. To retrieve and object:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];
   ```

If an object has not yet been set, it will return nil so you can do `if (username == nil) {`. `NSUserDefaults` are retained by the app even after an update.

You can read the docs for it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

One of the beste Core data Tutorials:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what data you want to save (how much, etc.)
It could be using NSUserDefault (prefered for small data, like user prefer has already opened the app once, so stop showing the tutorial), in a .plist, in a DataBase (CoreData/SQL)...

Comment: The data is small amount 3 words at most.